# How to navigate to another page using a button inside a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm designing a login form where the username and password get validated. If the user inputs are correct then I need to navigate to a different page else display an error message. The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to navigate to another page after validation. The only way I can switch to another page is by entering the html file's name directly in the form action attribute. Here is my code:

```
<form id="form" action="submit.php" target="_blank" method="post" >

<div class="container">
  <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
  <input id="usrname" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

  <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
  <input id="passwrd" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" 
  required>
    
  <button type="submit" onClick="validateForm()">Login</button>
</div>

</form>

<script>
  function validateForm() {

    var un = document.querySelector('#usrname').value;
    var pw = document.querySelector('#passwrd').value;
    var username = "admin";
    var password = "pass";

    if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
      alert('You are successfully logged in');
      location.replace("https://google.com")  
    }
    else {
      alert("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
      return false;
    }
  
  }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the if statement, replace this:

```
location.replace("https://google.com")
```

And try using this:

```
window.location.href= "https://google.com"
```